# jQuery stop script when item is not focused anymore

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote some code which is activated when user clicks on input box. I used `jQuery("#mydiv").focus();`, however, I ran into another problem. Once this is triggered, even if user lost focus from the input box the script runs and requires information wich results in another script breaking (i tried `.keyup()` and `.click()` everything had the same result). I want the script run only when the input box has focus, if user clicks off, the script should be inactive. Is it possible to do?

Comment: use `jQuery("#mydiv").blur()` to check that the input is no longer focused and set a setting to tell the other parts not to run

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the .blur event to undo whatever you have changed in your focus event.

So if on focus you (for example) changed the background colour of the box from white to blue, on the blur event you set the background back to white.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code I can only make a suggestion based on your description.

Try something like

```
$("mydiv").blur(function(){
   alert("Lost its focus.");
});
```

Also, if mydiv is a div then make sure that's what you want, it may be that you want to use your input control for the focus/blur.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the # on the mydiv jquery selector.